# WebDriver object has no attribute 'switch_to' in Selenium+Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Whenever I reach a JavaScript alert and try to interact with it, the test fails with an  AttributeError, 'WebDriver' (in this case, 'JsAlerts') object has no attribute switch_to. I am using selenium version 4.3.0 and Python 3.10. Here is what I've tried so far, with no success:

The "browsers" fixture just yields a WebDriver instance for Chrome.

**switch_to.alert:**

```
from objects.javascript_alerts import JsAlerts
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

def test_regular_alert(browsers):
    alerts = JsAlerts(browsers)
    alerts.load()
    alerts.click_go_to_js_alert()
    alerts.click_alert()
    WebDriverWait(alerts, 10).until(EC.alert_is_present())
    alerts.switch_to.alert.accept()
```

**importing Alert**

```
from objects.javascript_alerts import JsAlerts
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.alert import Alert

def test_regular_alert(browsers):
    alerts = JsAlerts(browsers)
    alerts.load()
    alerts.click_go_to_js_alert()
    alerts.click_alert()
    WebDriverWait(alerts, 10).until(EC.alert_is_present())
    al = Alert(alerts)
    al.accept()
```

I've also tried switch_to_alert()

Edit: Posting parts of the page object and fixture for more context.

**Page object**

```
class JsAlerts:
    # URL

    URL = 'https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/'

    # Locators

    add_js_alert_link = (By.LINK_TEXT, 'JavaScript Alerts')
    js_alert = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li:nth-child(1) > button")
    js_confirm = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li:nth-child(2) > button")
    js_prompt = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li:nth-child(3) > button")
    results = (By.ID, "result")

    # Initializer

    def __init__(self, browser):
        self.browser = browser

    # Interaction Methods

    def load(self):
        self.browser.get(self.URL)

    def click_go_to_js_alert(self):
        self.browser.find_element(*self.add_js_alert_link).click()

    def click_alert(self):
        self.browser.find_element(*self.js_alert).click()
```

**Fixture** (Chrome is set up in config)

```
@pytest.fixture
def browsers(config):
    # Initialize the ChromeDriver instance
    if config['browser'] == 'Firefox':
        b = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
    elif config['browser'] == 'Chrome':
        b = selenium.webdriver.Chrome()
    elif config['browser'] == 'Headless Chrome':
        opts = selenium.webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        opts.add_argument('headless')
        b = selenium.webdriver.Chrome(options=opts)
    else:
        raise Exception(f'Browser "{config["browser"]}" is not supported')

    # Return the WebDriver instance for the setup
    yield b

    # Quit the Webdriver instance for the cleanup
    b.quit()
```

Using browsers.switch_to.alert.accept() still returns the "'JsAlerts' object has no attribute switch_to " error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem

The error is telling you that your `JsAlerts` class does not have a method or property called `switch_to` which is correct. However, you're treating `JsAlerts` as if it is a `WebDriver` object.

For example, your line that does the following won't work because `Alert` expects a `WebDriver` object and you're passing in a custom `JsAlerts` object:

```py
# change this:
al = Alert(alerts)

# to this:
al = Alert(browsers)
```

The same is true for your `WebDriverWait` line:

```py
# change this:
WebDriverWait(alerts, 10)

# to this:
WebDriverWait(browsers, 10)
```

### Solutions

So, in your test, use the `WebDriver` object which *does* have the `switch_to` property you're looking for!

```py
def test_regular_alert(browsers):
    alerts = JsAlerts(browsers)
    alerts.load()
    alerts.click_go_to_js_alert()
    alerts.click_alert()
    WebDriverWait(browsers, 10).until(EC.alert_is_present())
    al = Alert(browsers)
    al.accept()
```

I tried the same exercise using [Pylenium](https://docs.pylenium.io) and this is what I came up with so you have a working example.

```py
# test_alers.py

from selenium.webdriver.common.alert import Alert
from pylenium.driver import Pylenium

from tests.ui.page import Page


def test_accept_alert(py: Pylenium):
    py.visit("https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/javascript_alerts")
    py.get("[onclick='jsAlert()']").click()
    alert: Alert = py.webdriver.switch_to.alert
    alert.accept()
    assert py.contains("You successfully clicked an alert")


def test_accept_alert_with_page_object(py: Pylenium):
    page = Page(py).goto()
    page.open_alert().accept()
    assert py.contains("You successfully clicked an alert")
```

And the page object that goes along with the second test

```py
# page.py

from selenium.webdriver.common.alert import Alert
from pylenium.driver import Pylenium


class Page:
    def __init__(self, py: Pylenium):
        self.py = py
        self.driver = py.webdriver

    def goto(self) -> "Page":
        self.py.visit("https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/javascript_alerts")
        return self

    def open_alert(self) -> Alert:
        self.py.get("[onclick='jsAlert()']").click()
        return self.driver.switch_to.alert
```

Answer (score 0):

Alert should be part of driver.

```
Browser.switch_to.alert.accept()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```py
alert = browser.switch_to.alert
```

and then perform tasks like `text`, `send_keys`, `accept`, `dismiss`

Comment: This only works if I don't use page objects/fixtures and I do everything in the same function. If I use browsers.switch_to.alert in the code I've posted above, I still get the same error. For more context, the JsAlerts page object does have a "self.browsers = browsers" init method.